# windows 10 became unresponsive after installing GCC ARM compiler

Tags: gcc, windows-10

I would really appreciate some help here or at least an indication of where to post this.

After unsuccessfully trying to make my programs run on e2studio, I installed GCC ARM compiler, and it made the program build successfully.

However my fast windows 10 computer is totally slow. It is unresponsive a lot of the time, it can not open any office anymore (in the task manager I can see they are running). The screen sometimes goes black. And mainly file explorer takes a lot of time to do the simplest of things. (it seems as any action takes a lot of processing)

In other words, I can't work normally in my computer anymore since I installed this compiler.

My disk resources are ample. No problem there. 
I am trying to savage all my work somehow since backing up now takes a lot of time

Any help would be greatly appreciated please. If you believe this does not goes here, instead of downvote me please help me redirect my problem to the appropriate place

Comment: Disable the installed anti-malware product and try again.

Comment: Would appreciate an explanation